How to convert a windows LDM Dynamic Disk to a Basic disk
I had an older drive that I left windows on, I went to clean out the old windows partitions in diskpart when I accidently deleted the reserved partition on a different drive. Windows auto converted that drive to a Dynamic drive.
Using ubuntu 24.04 on a usb stick I'd like to know if its possible to convert or delete the 2 LDM partitions and revert back to the "Microsoft reserved partitions" found on the other drives, making the drive once again "Basic".
Using gdisk it reports back that MBR: protective and GPT: present.
Edit: I have seen other articles/posts but those are often many years old and have different circumstances. In my case it's a Basic disk that was auto converted to dynamic by Windows after accidentally deleting the reserved (non system/os) partition. Ubuntu is able to mount, read, and write to the disk perfectly fine. This is why I believe my question is warranted: It's a newer post and points out that Ubuntu can now read and write to these types of drives. To me it's not too far fetched that Ubuntu could possibly now convert these types of disks.

It is not possible using Ubuntu tools.
Windows Dynamic Disk is a proprietary Windows feature. Open source developers have no access to the code, and can only guess how it might work.
The only tools for Windows Dynamic Disks are included with Windows.
Well, this guy says he can convert back to basic. Use this method at your own risk. We won't provide support if it doesn't work.

Testdisk can work under some cases. But really good backups required. https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1692248&p=10481110#post10481110 Partition tools repair tools often do not correct see the Windows system reserved partition as it is just unformatted space with a GUID that says it is System Reserved. Tools then think it is part of some other partition. Best to have a backup of the partition table with details, so you can restore that.

How is it that I can mount the disk perfectly fine in live boot and its reported as GPT table? Is there a specific reason as to why linux can't recreate the GPT table if it's able to navigate through the main partition perfectly fine?
